# How to create attribute for zone and set value in each zone using Ocean

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel, zone

I'm can't find the way how to create attributes for zones.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to the zones in the Wells namespace. Zone properties in Petrel are stored like horizon (=interface) properties but assigned to zones by a dynamic, global zone level. This is not exposed through Ocean as it is hard to understand and the side-effects are not predictable. Inside Petrel this is less so as the processes in question will update all the zone properties and keep them 'consistent'.

This zone behavior in Petrel is a concern and subject to change - another reason why Ocean does not expose an API.